# My Lumia 730 is unable to connect to any wifi router

Tags: wifi

I am facing problem connecting to any wifi router with my 6 months old lumia. Although lumia rolled out a ciritcal update but i am not able to update even with 3g data plan. It says it needs the wifi to download the update. :(

Is there is a way to get the update offline or with 3g data ?

Comment: Did you try connecting to a Wifi shared by a different smartphone?

Comment: I tried and failed.

Comment: Why can't you use 3g to download the update?

Comment: I tried that also but it struck at 0% http://s3.postimg.org/pd3t935zn/wp_ss_20151214_0001.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind resetting your phone you could reinstall your phone using the [Windows Devices Recovery Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987) - I'm not sure if this will install the latest build though. But it might fix your Wifi. Perhaps doing a hard reset beforehand might solve your connection issues as well.

Comment: It was working fine initially then my glass was broken and i formatted the phone before sending it to microsoft care. Now i am not able to download the critical update over wifi. i believe this critical update will fix this problem    .

Comment: Maybe there's a newer version available through the Recovery Tool than what you have installed last time - have you checked?

Comment: thanks Thomas, but it's too much to do so I went to the Microsoft Seller, they told me to hard reset.

Comment: well, that's what I did recommend you do first o.O